# Примитивный тип char ( char c=128; )

Tags: char, java

Здравствуйте!
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с примитивным типом char.

```
char c = 71;
System.out.println (c); \\ на выходе буква G
```

но, если присвоить значение более 127

```
c = 65000;
System.out.println (c); \\ если с>127 на выходе всегда знак '?'
```

Почему так происходит? Как вывести знак в таком случае? (интересует указание символа именно в 10-ричной системе счисления).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас проблемы с кодировкой или шрифтами в консоли. 
Java здесь не причем, символы она представляет корректно: https://ideone.com/b157B5